# Fast Python spring network solver

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I wanted a very simple spring system written in Python. The system would be defined as a simple network of `knots`, linked by `links` using the following rules:

- A `knot` is a massless connection between links. Each knot is only affected by the push/pull forces it receives from the links it is connected to (no gravity, viscosity etc.)... Its only attribute is to be anchored or not, where an anchored knot affects the system by its movement. An unanchored knot can also affect the system if being moved, but it will be pulled back by the resulting push/pull forces.
- A `link` is a connection between 2 knots. It has no mass, and it applies force on the knots connected to each end derived from the difference between its current length and its initial length.
- The system takes for input the `initial position` of each `knot`, each `knot's` `anchored state`, a list of `links` (presented as arrays of `knot` indices), and each link's `initial lengths`. The system then begins iterating over the network by adding up all the `forces` affecting each `knot`, adjusting the `knots` to a their new position (dampened for stability), and keep iterating until an iteration count limit is reached, or the highest `force` applied at any given iteration is below a given threshold. I don't care to solve over time, I don't need velocity, all I want is the final "relaxed" position of each `knot`.

Leveraging NumPy's vectorization, I came up with this code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

def solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0, cycles=1000, precision=0.001, dampening=0.1, debug=False):
    """
    kPos       : vector array - knot position
    kAnchor    : float array  - knot's anchor state, 0 = moves freely, 1 = anchored (not moving)
    link0      : int array    - array of links connecting each knot. each index corresponds to a knot
    link1      : int array    - array of links connecting each knot. each index corresponds to a knot
    w0         : float array  - initial link length
    cycles     : int          - eval stops when n cycles reached
    precision  : float        - eval stops when highest applied force is below this value
    dampening  : float        - keeps system stable during each iteration
    """

    kPos        = np.asarray(kPos)
    pos         = np.array(kPos) # copy of kPos
    kAnchor     = 1-np.clip(np.asarray(kAnchor).astype(float),0,1)[:,None]
    link0       = np.asarray(link0).astype(int)
    link1       = np.asarray(link1).astype(int)
    w0          = np.asarray(w0).astype(float)

    F = np.zeros(pos.shape)
    i = 0

    for i in xrange(cycles):

        # Init force applied per knot
        F = np.zeros(pos.shape)

        # Calculate forces
        AB = pos[link1] - pos[link0] # get link vectors between knots
        w1 = np.sqrt(inner1d(AB,AB)) # get link current lengths
        AB/=w1[:,None] # normalize link vectors
        f = (w1 - w0) # calculate force
        f = f[:,None] * AB # calculate force vector

        # Apply force vectors on each knot
        np.add.at(F, link0, f)      # F[link0] += f*AB
        np.subtract.at(F, link1, f) # F[link1] -= f*AB

        # Update point positions       
        pos += F * dampening * kAnchor

        # If the maximum force applied is below our precision criteria, exit
        if np.amax(F) < precision:
            break

    # Debug info
    if debug:
        print 'Iterations: %s'%i
        print 'Max Force:  %s'%np.amax(F)

    return pos
```

Here's some test data to show how it works. In this case I'm using a grid, but in reality the network can be of any shape or form:

```
import cProfile

# Create a 5x5 3D knot grid
z = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 5)
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 5)[::-1]
x,z = np.meshgrid(x,z)
kPos = np.array([np.array(thing) for thing in zip(x.flatten(), z.flatten())])
kPos = np.insert(kPos, 1, 0, axis=1)
'''
array([[-0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.5 ],
       [-0.25,  0.  ,  0.5 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.5 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.5 ],
       [ 0.25,  0.  , -0.5 ],
       [ 0.5 ,  0.  , -0.5 ]])
'''


# Define the links connecting each knots
link0 = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
link1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
AB    = kPos[link0]-kPos[link1]
w0    = np.sqrt(inner1d(AB,AB)) # this is a square grid, each link's initial length will be 0.25

# Set the anchor states
kAnchor = np.zeros(len(kPos)) # All knots will be free floating
kAnchor[12] = 1 # Middle knot will be anchored
```

This is what the grid looks like:

[image: Grid at rest]

If we run my code using this data, nothing will happen since the links aren't pushing or pulling:

```
print np.allclose(kPos,solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0, debug=True))
# Returns True
# Iterations: 0
# Max Force:  0.0
```

Now let's move that middle anchored knot up a bit and solve the system:

```
# Move the center knot up a little
kPos[12] = np.array([0,0.3,0])

# eval the system
new = solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0, debug=True) # positions will have moved
#Iterations: 102
#Max Force:  0.000976603249133

# Rerun with cProfile to see how fast it runs
cProfile.run('solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0)')
# 520 function calls in 0.008 seconds
```

And here's what the grid looks like after being pulled by that single anchored knot:

[image]

## Question

This grid example solves plenty fast, but my actual use cases are a little more complex than this example (~100-200 knots, ~300-500 links) and solve too slow. I'm looking for ways to make this faster. I did try to get rid of the square root calls at every iteration, which didn't make much of a difference.

I did try to cythonize my program (see below) in hopes to improve performance, but with my very limited C knowledge the final performance was far worse.

If anyone can show me ways to speed up its current pure Python implementation, or could show me ways to properly cythonize my function, I would be very grateful.

Here's my very naive Cython version:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double sqrt(double m)


import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_f
ctypedef np.int64_t DTYPE_i

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)


def eval(np.ndarray[DTYPE_f, ndim=2] kPos,
                np.ndarray[DTYPE_f, ndim=1] kAnchor,
                np.ndarray[DTYPE_i, ndim=1] link0,
                np.ndarray[DTYPE_i, ndim=1] link1,
                np.ndarray[DTYPE_f, ndim=1] w0,
                int cycles=100,
                precision=0.001,
                dampening=0.1,
                debug=False):


    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j, k, nKnots, nLinks
    cdef double w1
    cdef double f
    cdef double maxF

    nKnots = len(kPos)
    nLinks = len(link0)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_f, ndim=2] pos = np.array(kPos)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_f, ndim=2] F = np.zeros((nKnots,3))
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_f, ndim=1] AB

    for i in range(cycles):
        F = np.zeros((nKnots,3))


        # Calculate forces
        for j in range(nLinks):
            AB = pos[link1[j]] - pos[link0[j]]
            w1 = sqrt(AB[0]**2 + AB[1]**2 + AB[2]**2)

            if w1 > 0:
                AB/=w1
                f = w1 - w0[j]
                F[link0[j]] += f * AB
                F[link1[j]] -= f * AB

        # Update point positions
        for j in range(nKnots):
            if kAnchor[j] < 1:
                w1 = sqrt(F[j][0]**2 + F[j][1]**2 + F[j][2]**2)

                if maxF < w1:
                    maxF = w1

                pos[j] = pos[j] + F[j] * dampening * (1-kAnchor[j])


        if maxF < precision:
            break


    # Debug info
    if debug:
        print 'Iterations: %s'%i
        print 'Max Force:  %s'%maxF


    return pos
```

Comment: Something is wrong, possibly with the test. Since only one knot is anchored I expect the whole grid to move 0.3 up. Why does it deform at all?

Comment: Not really a speed up but you should probably use `__debug__` instead of `debug`. As in there is a predefined constant `__debug__` made specifically for the purpose that you use `debug` in...

Comment: @vnp if you walk through the algorithm it makes sense. At the very first iteration, only the links connected to the anchored knot have changed (they're longer than initial length), this causes a force pulling the connected knots, the anchored one doesn't change so it's immediate neighbors get pulled in. 2nd iteration the same knots get pulled again towards the anchor but this time they get resistance from the links to their neighbors who didn't move last cycle. Those neighbors also get a force pulling them inward... so on and so forth until one of the end conditions are met.

Comment: Before we dive into an algorithm, let's check the physics. In the final configuration I see the force pulling a `(0,1)` knot up, and I don't see the force which would counteract it.

Comment: @vpn re: first comment: Imagine this grid example is square cloth. If you pinch the center with your fingers and move up, the whole cloth won't remain square. In the code example, the system's 1st iteration sees the links `(11,12),(12,13),(7,12),(12,17)` as being longer than initial, this will generate forces on knots `(7,11,13,17)` to move towards the center. 2nd iteration all links connected these knots will differ from their initial lengths, and will in turn generate forces on all connected knots. Each iteration produces forces until all links are (almost) back at their original lengths.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Jaime's solution, I noticed that `np.bincount` was being called in each loop iteration.  This function seems to compute the mapping between links and knots, which is something that doesn't change in any loop iteration, at least as I understand your program.  Thus I wondered if things would get factor by eliminating this repeated function call.

One way to do that is to represent the mapping between links and knots as a connectivity matrix.  This matrix takes up more memory than the simple lists `link0` and `link1`, especially if dense, but if that tradeoff is acceptable, it would allow just using a single `np.dot()` call in each loop, rather than two different `np.bincount` calls in each iteration.  Effectively Jaime's code is a kind of sparse dot product, while this code uses the dense dot product.

A nice bonus of this approach is that the code in the loop becomes much simpler.

```
def faster_solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0, cycles=1000, precision=0.001, dampening=0.1, debug=False):
    ### <CODE AS BEFORE> ###
    num_links = len(link0)

    # form links data into a connectivity matrix
    cnxn_mat = np.zeros((knots, num_links), dtype = 'int')
    for ix in range(num_links):
        cnxn_mat[link0[ix], ix] = 1
        cnxn_mat[link1[ix], ix] = -1
    ### <...> ###

    for i in xrange(cycles):

        # Init force applied per knot
        F = np.zeros(pos.shape)

        # Calculate forces
        AB = pos[link1] - pos[link0] # get link vectors between knots
        w1 = inner1d(AB, AB) ** 0.5 # get link current lengths
        AB /= w1[:, None] # normalize link vectors
        f = (w1 - w0) # calculate force
        f = f[:, None] * AB # calculate force vector

        F = np.dot(cnxn_mat, f)

        # Update point positions       
        ### <CONTINUE W/ PREVIOUS CODE>
```

I did actually time this version vs. the old version using the small test case in the OP, and there was an improvement, but it wasn't very dramatic.  My untested guess is that my approach will be much more efficient as the problem size increases, *if* the density of links between knots is large.  The caveat is that much larger amounts of memory will likely be required.  (If instead there are a tremendous number of knots but relatively few links, Jaime's sparse approach might well be faster.)

```
# Create a 5x5 3D knot grid
z = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 5)
x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 5)[::-1]
x,z = np.meshgrid(x,z)
kPos = np.array([np.array(thing) for thing in zip(x.flatten(), z.flatten())])
kPos = np.insert(kPos, 1, 0, axis=1)

# Define the links connecting each knots
link0 = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
link1 = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

AB    = kPos[link0]-kPos[link1]
w0    = np.sqrt(inner1d(AB,AB)) # this is a square grid, each link's initial length will be 0.25

# Set the anchor states
kAnchor = np.zeros(len(kPos)) # All knots will be free floating
kAnchor[12] = 1 # Middle knot will be anchored

# Move the center knot up a little
kPos[12] = np.array([0,0.3,0])

# Compare both methods
fnew, new = (
            faster_solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0),
            solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0)
             )
assert np.all(np.isclose(fnew, new))

# Time both methods
%timeit fnew = faster_solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0) # positions will have moved
%timeit new = solver(kPos, kAnchor, link0, link1, w0) # positions will have moved

100 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.25 ms per loop
```

***UPDATE***:

After a nice comment from the OP with new data, it seems that at larger systems my proposed improvement didn't help at all.  With my method, the larger system would require creating a dense 5000-by-2000 matrix.  However if I understand the problem then this matrix with 10,000,000 elements will have only 4000 nonzero values.  Sparsification would seem to be in order.  The question is which of the various [sparse formats supported by SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) would be best.  I did some empirical testing and found that for matrices in which every column has two entries at random rows, the "CSR" and "COO" formats seemed to be best.

```
# construct a random sparse matrix in dense format that has entries in every column, but very few in rows
np.random.seed(1)
n_rows, n_cols = (2000, 5000)

col_idx = np.concatenate((xrange(n_cols), xrange(n_cols)))
row_idx = np.random.randint(n_rows, size = 2*n_cols)

data = np.concatenate(([1]*n_cols, [-1]*n_cols))

random_mat = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype = 'float')

mat_coo = random_mat
mat_csr = random_mat.tocsr()
mat_full = random_mat.todense()
arr_full = random_mat.toarray()

# a random dense vector
v = np.random.rand(n_cols)

# timings
print "FULL MATRIX:"
%timeit _ = np.dot(mat_full, v)
print "\n"

print "FULL ARRAY:"
%timeit _ = np.dot(arr_full, v)
print "\n"

print "COO:"
%timeit _ = mat_coo.dot(v)
print "\n"

print "CSR:"
%timeit _ = mat_csr.dot(v)
print "\n"

print "bincount:"
link0, link1 = row_idx[0:n_cols], row_idx[n_cols:]

ndim = 3
out = np.zeros(shape = (n_rows, ndim))
def my_loop():
    ndim = 3
    for dim in xrange(ndim):
        out[:, dim] = np.bincount(link0, weights = v, minlength = n_rows) - np.bincount(link1, weights = v, minlength = n_rows)
    return out
%timeit my_loop()




FULL MATRIX:
100 loops, best of 3: 4.67 ms per loop


FULL ARRAY:
100 loops, best of 3: 4.66 ms per loop


COO:
The slowest run took 5.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.5 µs per loop


CSR:
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.3 µs per loop


bincount:
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.4 µs per loop
```

Minor other note: using `dtype = 'int` in my original `faster_solver` code was a mistake.  Although it results in a better (lower memory, more precise) representation of the connectivity matrix, eventually this matrix will be multiplied by a `float` vector, `f`, which requires that `numpy` convert all the elements to `float` anyway.  It's (slightly) more efficient to instantiate the matrix with a `dtype = 'float'` for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your suggestion does make the code nice and tidy, but gets slower when you scale the system. I just tried it in one of my real world applications (~2000 knots, ~5000 links) and the difference is significant: cProfile clocks `solver` at  0.736s, and`fast_solver` at 54.290s. On smaller systems (~400 knots, ~800 links) it goes down to  0.136s vs 1.057s. I'm sure there's a threshold where your  solution is consistently faster, when i find it i'll use your suggestion as an optimization.

Comment: Thanks your the reply and for trying this code on your larger systems.    I guess making a regular dense numpy matrix of size 2000-by-5000 is not a good idea after all.  The alternative is to use `scipy.sparse` to speed things up.  I tried this on the very small toy example and it didn't help much, but I'd be curious to see how things work out on the bigger system.

Comment: Also, I implemented a sparse dot product for your type of connectivity matrix and it does seem to be faster than `np.bincount`.  Would love to get @Jaime 's thoughts on this.

Comment: [I asked my question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520384/improving-a-numpy-implementation-of-a-simple-spring-network), user @Bill proposed using a sparse matrix. [You can see a 3d version here](https://gist.github.com/will-bainbridge/1579cd3c8de338c7df4e). The problem was that i couldn't get it to behave like my algorithm. Ex: if only one point was anchored and moved, the whole system would move with it. The iterative nature of my algorithm made the non-anchored points drag behind. btw, i used a grid as an example, but i need it to work with any type of layout.

Comment: I don't understand.  The sparse matrix dot product provides a result that is exactly equivalent to your original algorithm as coded in *this* question.  What behavior are you looking for?  What algorithm are you talking about?  (BTW cross-posting the same question to multiple SE sites is bad form; in the future please don't.)

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't seen your results and my previous attempt at using sparse matrices was flawed and led me to the wrong conclusion. I implemented your suggestion, using a COO matrix which seemed the fastest. In a real life "large non grid system" test i got a speed increase about 10% over bincount. So thank you very much for your insight.

Answer (score 6):

You should profile your code, to figure out what exactly is it that is slowing your code down. It's hard to tell without some actual measurements, but my bet is on your calls to `np.add.at` and `np.minus.at`, as the `.at()` method is notoriously (very) slow. For some operations there is really no alternative, but for addition/subtraction you can use `np.bincount`. The transformed code would look something like:

```
knots, ndim = kPos.shape
...
for dim in range(ndim):
    # Apply force vectors on each dimension of each knot
    F[:, dim] = (np.bincount(link0, weights=f[:, dim], minlength=knots) -
                 np.bincount(link1, weights=f[:, dim], minlength=knots))
```

As I said, you'll need to test it, but I wouldn't be surprised if this little change makes your code 5-10x faster.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! The speed difference is difficult to quantize but its definitely significant. To test i set the max iteration count to a large number, so the only end condition is that the highest applied force be below my threshold. On a small simple example (10x10 grid, 100 knots, 180 links) the difference is 0.17s vs 0.59 = ~2.88 times faster. But on a larger grid (50x50 grid, 2500 knots, 4900 links) it goes to 23.89s vs 3.29 = >7x faster. This is definitely a big boost! Do you have any recommendations for profiling (i'm using cProfile)... also fyi F[dim] should be F[:,dim].

Comment: Oops! Fixed the assignment index mistake, thanks. And unfortunately no, I don't know of any good profiling tools, sorry.

Comment: [Profiling tools](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5284/52915)

Answer (score 1):

To compute the link current lengths, maybe [numpy.linalg.norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) can be useful.

```
w1 = np.sqrt(inner1d(AB,AB)) # get link current lengths
```

Becomes (no sure about the `axis` value)

```
w1 = np.linalg.norm(AB, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately np.linalg.norm is a bit slower than the square root of inner1d.